# How can I use a Linux terminal to communicate with a Windows user?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, windows-10

Me and my buddy are beginner computer enthusiasts. I have Ubuntu and he has Windows 10. Any way I can use the terminal to communicate with him? Currently, when I type **ytalk user@ipaddress** the program notes that he doesn't have a talk daemon. We both want to use a minimalist shell-type interface, since they have such an old-school charm. How would we go about this?
Also, I don't know if this is important, but all of my friend's ports are firewalled.

Comment: There are myriad ways to send a message from one computer to another.  Even if you both weren't computer nerds, you would be aware of this, so there is something about all of the commonly known ways that don't meet your needs.  You need to get more specific about your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Hopefully my question is a lot clearer now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use gtalk or any equivalent.

- setup a user account for your friend on your host.
- have him install putty
- set your router to allow remote ssh
- have your friend log in
- now he can use talk from hos remote session on your computer.

the caveat is that your computer is now on internet, it might not be safe.

In order to protect yourself :

- have real password (you, friend, root account)
- disable root login ( from `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` )
- disable password authentification ( same as above )
- change ssh port from 22 to any number above 65536
- use ipv6
- use daily ipv6